# jQuery fadeIn: Children should not be faded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built an collapsable tree with *li* and *ul* elements. I am using the **jQuery.fadeIn** and **jQuery.fadeOut** to collapse respectively show branches in the tree by applying these functions to nested *ul* elements.

Works nearly perfect, but a small problem appears when collapsed branches are shown: If the branch to show contains collapsed branches itself, the collapse state of these branches will not be preserved meaning that all the child branches will also be shown.

```
<li id="branch1"> Item 1
  <ul style="display:none">
    <li> Branch 1
      <ul style="display:none">
       ...
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If I now call the following, also the *Branch 1* will be faded in.

```
jQuery("#branch1 ul").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Unless you provide some code sample, we are unable to help!

Comment: I have updated the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your query is getting both the elements. $('#branch1 ul') returns them both. Use this to get just the first one:

```
            var a= jQuery("#branch1>ul")
             a.fadeIn();
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was my problem by applying the function to multiple elements using an incorrect jQuery-selector. The function should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure be like this

```
  <ul>
    <li id="branch1"> Item 1 </li>
     <ul style="display:none">
      <li> Branch 1</li>
       <ul style="display:none">
       <li> Branch 3</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
```

in this structure your jQuery code will be work .

```
           jQuery("#branch1 ul").fadeIn();
```